# Django REST: Best way to render image out of varchar bytes string?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-rest-framework

**Running**: Windows 7, Python 3.3, Django 1.6.5, Django Rest Framework.

**Background:** We've created a sql server databse with Django and REST on top that we post Log files to via http.  These files are saved into the SQL databse by Django.  One of the fields for each Log record, is a screenshot field.  This field contains base64 binary data of the JPEG (or the hexadecimal interpretation of that binary data I guess) in a `varchar(max)` field.

Now we want to be able to display the screenshot on the webpage for each test.

**Question:** How can we render the image for the users' browser?  Should we decode the base64 byte stream and save the image in a seperate directory on the server, and just display that image on each page?  Or is there a way to render the bytes every time the page is requested?

Comment: What do you mean? you can both render a base64 or use a local file, I would opt for the second method, rendering base64 images in HTML is not Django related, but rather browser related.

Comment: @petkostas would you be able to detail how you would implement both approaches?  For example, could you use the `<img>` tag and provide the binary or hex string instead of a filepath? I'm a web novice.  If you provide thorough answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to solve the same problem (albeit using one of the new `BinaryField` types).